# How to pass values between functional components in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to pass isAuthenticated value between the two funtional components (`SignInOutlookAccount` & `SignInOutlookButton`)
but i can't get its value.

How can i take `isAuthenticated` vaule from `SignInOutlookAccount.jsx` to `SignInOutlookButton.jsx`?

**SignInOutlookAccount.jsx**

```
export const getUserProfile = async (props) => {
console.log("im inside getUserProfile");

try {
    var accessToken = await userAgentApplication.acquireTokenSilent({
        scopes: config.scopes
    });
    console.log("im inside tryyyyyy");

    if (accessToken) {
        var user = await getUserDetails(accessToken);

        props = {
            isAuthenticated: true,
            user: {
                displayName: user.displayName,
                email: user.mail || user.userPrincipalName,
                accessToken: user.accessToken
            },
            error: null
        };
    }
    } catch (err) {
    var error = {};
    if (typeof err === "string") {
        var errParts = err.split("|");
        error =
            errParts.length > 1
                ? { message: errParts[1], debug: errParts[0] }
                : { message: err };
    } else {
        error = {
            message: err.message,
            debug: JSON.stringify(err)
        };
    }

    props = {
        isAuthenticated: false,
        user: {},
        error: error
    };
}
```

**SignInOutlookButton.jsx**

```
export const SignInOutlookButton = ({props}) => {
 return <Button text={isAuthenticated ? 'Sign In' : 'Sign Out'} startIcon={<Mail />} onClick={()=> login(props)} />;
};
```

**CustomComponents.jsx**

```
export const CustomComponents = props => {
return (<SignInOutlookButton/>);
```

};

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass state between functional components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57048416/how-do-i-pass-state-between-functional-components)

Answer (score 2):

In your `SignInOutlookButton` you are destructuring `props` to get a property called `props`. Don't do that. This will look for a prop called `props`. You most likely are not calling the component like this: `<SignInOutlookButton props={...myProps} />` if you are, don't.

Once you change the function declaration to be correct:

```js
export const SignInOutlookButton = (props) => {
```

You can access the `isAuthenticated` through props: `text={props.isAuthenticated`.

Comment: I call the component like this <SignInOutlookButton/>.
I changed everything as you said but the props.isAuthenticated is still undefined.

Comment: You need to pass it the prop: `<SignInOutlookButton isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} />`

Comment: export const CustomComponents = props => {
return (<SignInOutlookButton isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated});
};

I call it in a functional component so is still undefined

Comment: Explain what you mean? Being in a functional component is irrelevant.

Comment: I see your update. You have to pass it a value somehow. Just because you saved a variable in one component does not magically make it available in another. It's a basic scoping issue. Without more code I can't guess any further. I assumed you were calling the component from within `SignInOutlookAccount`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<SignInOutlookButton isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} />
```

And export the component like that

```
export const SignInOutlookButton = (props) => {
  const { isAuthenticated } = props;

  return <Button text={isAuthenticated ? 'Sign Out' : 'Sign In'} 
    startIcon={<Mail />} onClick={()=> login(props)} />;
};
```

Comment: I call SignInOutlookButton in another functional component which i added the example above. I tried like this and it doesn't work is still undefined

Comment: The answer before from Brian Thompson works too btw